# How to virtualize Win10 from Linux (into VirtualBox on Linux) and shrink it?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk, cloning

Basically, what I need could be similar to what most other people running Windows for work would want, I suppose, so let us get started on my requirements:

1. Somehow copy a raw disk (e.g. `/dev/sda`) onto a bigger medium. In my case, Windows is stored on a 1TB SATA SSD and I want to clone it into the VirtualBox VDI format and store it onto my bigger NVMe SSD medium which has about 1.5TB of free space.
2. After making proper adjustments to the VirtualBox VM settings, start the VM up.
3. Free as much of the VM's disk space as possible, such as
   uninstalling games, etc.. which are irrelevant to the VM's use case.
4. Then, shrink the VM's disk to the minimum (used space only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unmount all of the Win10 partition(s) if mounted.
2. Go to a directory, where you want to store the new image.
3. Make yourself the superuser or use `sudo` in front:

   ```
   VBoxManage convertfromraw /dev/sda win10.vdi --format=VDI
   ```
4. After it has been completed, open the user shell, and change ownership to your user, example follows:

   ```
   chown vlastimil:vlastimil win10.vdi && chmod 666 win10.vdi
   ```
5. The following VirtualBox setup may be taken as a template, tweak it to your needs:

   [image]
6. Note, that I have already installed VirtualBox Extension Pack and Guest additions.
7. At this point, I suppose you have a few hundred GBs to shrink off of the VM. Try deleting movies and other useless stuff for the VM if not.
8. Now, we may differ in the approach. I chose to shrink the C: partition with *some tool*, there is no affiliation between me and *this tool*:

   [image]
9. Using *the tool*, shrink C:, possibly do other changes in order to have a large free space at the end of the disk.
10. Using the good old [MS tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete), also clean free space on C: drive (`sdelete -z c:`).
11. Shut down the VM. Close VirtualBox.
12. Finally, use this command to shrink the VM's disk off of all zeroed parts (no need for `sudo`):

    ```
    VBoxManage modifymedium win10.vdi --compact
    ```
13. Be aware the last step you cannot watch e.g. with `ls -l`, it will not reveal the shrunk size until 100% finished.