# VirtualBox 7.0 guest freezes whenever the guest is switched into full-screen mode, fix?

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, virtual-machine, freeze

On my Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon running an `nvidia-driver-530`...

VirtualBox 7.0 guest freezes whenever the guest is switched into full-screen mode. The exact version follows:

```
$ apt-cache policy virtualbox-7.0 
virtualbox-7.0:
  Installed: 7.0.8-156879~Ubuntu~jammy
  Candidate: 7.0.8-156879~Ubuntu~jammy
  Version table:
 *** 7.0.8-156879~Ubuntu~jammy 500
        500 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy/contrib amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

... has only one guest machine = Win10 Pro version 22H2 (not a clean install, but [virtualized physical machine according to this one of my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/732651/126755).

Guest additions were updated to the latest version both in VirtualBox itself, and inside the Win10 VM.

I tried connecting remotely for an hour or more using different tools (RDP clients). I believed this is the way around the issue. Fail was what I accepted as a result in the end.

At this point I am unsure what causes the issue, and how exactly to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, disabling 3D acceleration helped and fixed the issue:

[image: disabling 3D acceleration]